# Node server - Is there a way to run something every x amount of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs server that runs some scripts and parses files for my client to access. The data sits on certain urls and I fetch that on the client side. The problem is that the data will be out of date, so the script will need to be ran again. Is there a way to run these scripts in my server every say 15 minutes and post that to the url?

Comment: maybe setTimeout everytime the client parses the file, and run a function to clear the database  after a suitable time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need is something like job scheduling. There are few ways to achieve it:

1. You can handle in your Nodejs application

- Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method to repeatedly calls a function. However, this method is not fully supported by Nodejs - look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#browser_compatibility). Just remind that timer methods in Nodejs maybe delay your task because the [event-loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) mechanism
- Use the job scheduling library that allows you to schedule the recurring task. There are 2 libs as I did a quick search: [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) and [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

2. Create a system cron-job to trigger your Nodejs app to handle the recurring task. Check out more at [here](https://www.guru99.com/crontab-in-linux-with-examples.html).